# Java Classes compiling 64bit 32bit

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit

When compiling a Java-Class in a 32bit environment ( JDK ) does this class also run on a
64bit JRE ? Or do I have to compile the class in a 64bit JDK ?

The class does not have any JNI ( Java native Interface ).

regards

Comment: Java bytecode is internally always 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it does. the bytecode does NOT depend on the architecture of the environment (the clarification of JNI helped a lot in giving a clear answer).

Comment: Thanks you and all others helping me.